# How to write better code in es6 for formatting an object with array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I wanted to get a better solution using map functions to get the same desired result.

I am formatting an object for chartJs for chart with bar values.

But I am using an old method of es5 syntax, I wanted to achieve the same using the es6 syntax.

I have tried using es5 syntax like for.. in loop to get the desired result.

```
var graphData = [
  {org: 1234, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 107},
  {org: 123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 1373},
  {org: 123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900,dpt3: 946}, 
  {org: 34634634, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 715}, 
  {org: 123123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 276}
 ];
```

actual data to be parsed into an object with key and values from all the objects

```
var graphdataObj = {}; 
graphData.forEach(function(elem) {
   for (var key in elem) { 
     if (graphdataObj[key]) {
        graphdataObj[key].push(elem[key]);
     } else {
        graphdataObj[key] = [];
        graphdataObj[key].push(elem[key]);
     }
  };
});
```

parsed/result object ==> graphdataObj

```
graphdataObj = {
  dpt1: [1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500]
  dpt2: [900, 900, 900, 900, 900]
  dpt3: [107, 1373, 946, 715, 276] 
  org: [1234, 123, 123, 34634634, 123123]
};
```

I wanted to get the same result using es6 syntax, for some other better solution than this without using for .. in loop in forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `reduce` and iterate over the `Object.entries` of each item of `graphData`, creating an array value at the key in the accumulator if it doesn't exist yet, then push to that array:

```js
const graphData = [
  {org: 1234, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 107},
  {org: 123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 1373},
  {org: 123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900,dpt3: 946}, 
  {org: 34634634, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 715}, 
  {org: 123123, dpt1: 1500, dpt2: 900, dpt3: 276}
];
 
const graphdataObj = graphData.reduce((a, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
    a[key].push(val);
  });
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(graphdataObj);
```

Note that `forEach` is still used, inside the `.reduce` (but `forEach` *is* the most appropriate array method for generic iteration over an array for the purpose of side effects - there's no more appropriate method than `forEach` at that point, so it's not something to worry about).

Answer (score 0):

### Why not `reduce` without `forEach`

You can easily avoid using a `.forEach` as per @CertainPerfomance's answer by using `.reduce`. However, you can also avoid using `.forEach` within the `.reduce` method as well by using a `for ... of` loop.

```
graphData.reduce((data, el) => {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(el)) {
    if (!data[key]) {
      data[key] = [];
    }
    data[key].push(val);
  }
  return data;
}, {});
```

It's basically the same idea, but I don't see the reason to use `.forEach` when you can use the classic `for ... of`, which, in my opinion, is **much more readable**.